# How to create multiple circles scattered within a bounding box

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JS and HTML and I am struggling with the following task - 
create draggable set of circles (randomly scattered on 2d plane).

I managed to create one circle - [check_here](https://jsfiddle.net/rm55v69f/2/)

But I do not know how to create arbitrary many (as many as user specifies). 
Because right now circle is a div element in html body. 
So I have no idea how to approach creating multiple of those randomly scattered within some bounding box.

Any help? 
THANK YOU

```
<html>
<style>

</style>
<body>

<div id="circle"></div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById(("circle")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;


    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a couple of hints how to do this:

First, you can create new divs in your scripts, beyond just the ones specified in your HTML using `document.createElement('div')`, and append those divs to the body of your document with `document.body.appendChild(myDiv)`.

Second, you can use a `class`, rather than an `id`, to specify each div displays a circle -- `id`s have to be unique, but multiple elements can be the same class.

Using the above info, and stuff you've already figured out how to do in your code, should get you pretty far solving this problem.